# How to compare multiple rows of the same SQL table

Tags: sql-server

Assuming I have a SQL Server table that looks like this:

```
id   valA   valB   valC
-----------------------
1    1      2      3
2    4      5      6
3    7      8      9
3    10     11     12
4    13     14     15
4    16     14     15
```

I want to compare rows to find those with certain data matching. In this case I want to identify rows with matching id, valB, and valC, so it should find only the last two rows. The contents of the valA column are ignored.

Then I want to delete one of the two rows and I will then adjust the valA column as needed.  My trouble is identifying the matching rows.

From a lot of other similar questions on this site, I tried various things similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.id
FROM
    newtable A
INNER JOIN 
    newtable B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    A.valB = B.valB AND
    A.valC = B.valC
```

but I end up getting all four ids. I'm not sure why. Even if that worked, I'm still not sure how to proceed with the update and delete actions I need to take on all the matching rows found. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: what parameter you will pass ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close.  You just need to *exclude* the rows you don't want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id
FROM newtable A INNER JOIN
     newtable B
     ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.valB = B.valB AND
      A.valC = B.valC AND
      A.valA <> B.valA;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm understanding now why all the rows appeared, because it was finding a match between a given row and the same row in the other (same) table.  The problem with adding what you have is that valA contents may sometimes match.  I think I could fix that by having a unique id field in the table.

Comment: @AngeloQ . . . Yes, a unique id would solve the problem that I'm trying to solve with the comparison on `valA`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use <kbd>[HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)</kbd>.If you have these type of queries a lot indexing `HASHBYTES` column will help in comparisons..

<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/623743/how-to-compare-multiple-rows-of-the-same-sql-table)</kbd>

```
create table #temp
(
id int,
vala int,
valb int,
valc int
)

insert into #temp
select 1,2,3,4
union all
select 4,8,10,12
union all
select 1,5,3,4

;With cte
as
(
select *,
dense_rank() over (  order by (HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',CONCAT(id,valb,valc)))) as rownum
from #temp
)
select * from cte where rownum>1
```

or you could just use DenseRank..

```
;With cte
as
(
select *,
dense_rank() over (  order by id,valb,valc) as rownum
from #temp
)
select * from cte where rownum>1
```

Comment: Thanks, good ideas.  MSSQL complained about CONCAT in the first example.  The second example ran, but produced the entire table, just ordered by id.

Answer (score 1):

> ... My trouble is identifying the matching rows.

To select the matching rows use this:

```
;with x as (

select *, count(*) over (partition by id, valb, valc) as N from YourTable

)


-- matching values
select x.id, x.vala, x.valb, x.valc from x where x.N > 1
```

> ...I'm still not sure how to proceed with the update and delete actions...

```
-- deleting from YourTable where id, valb and val c are repeated and vala != valb - 1
delete from x 

where x.N > 1

and x.vala != x.valb -1
```

I advice to do a select before to see what is going to be deleted.

---

> Fiddle select matches: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae27b/5
>
> Fiddle delete from: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae27b/2
>
> Include the ROW_NUMBER of the record in the original table (ordered by Id): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae27b/14

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work best for me.  I'm getting this error from MSSQL Server 2005 though: "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported."  But it still runs and seems to give the expected results.

Comment: Also, how would I get the row number, or what other way would be easiest to go back to that row in the original table.  I actually see that I can't simply delete the second row until I first merge the two together.  I need to check contents of valA (and other columns) and copy values before deleting the second row.

Answer (score 1):

tell your requirement lil more,like what parameter you will pass etc

you can try this,

```
declare @t table(id int,valA int,valB int,valC int)
insert into @t values
(1  ,  1   ,   2   ,   3 )
,(2  ,  4   ,   5   ,   6 )
,(3  ,  7   ,   8   ,   9 )
,(3  ,  10  ,   11  ,   12)
,(4  ,  13  ,   14  ,   15)
,(4  ,  16  ,   14  ,   15)

;With CTE as
(
select * ,row_number()over(partition by id,valb,valc order by id)rn
from @t
)
,CTE1 as
(
select * from cte   
where rn>1
)
select * from @t t
where EXISTS(
select id from cte1 c where t.id=c.id)
```

Comment: This approach will work for the delete as well...

DELETE FROM @t as t
WHERE EXISTS (select 'x' from cte1 as c where t.id = c.id)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the id for which there is atleast two rows with same valb and valc, you can use this:

```
select distinct 
    id
from t
group by
    id, valb, valc
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you need to get the other columns as well, you can use window function `count` like this:

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        count(*) over (partition by id, valb, valc) cnt
    from t
) t where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: The first example with group is a good idea, as long as the SELECT includes columns that are in the GROUP BY, otherwise it gives me an error.  I may be able to work with that though.  The second example didn't work for me, perhaps a syntax error?  I tried to fix it but was not able.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify all the columns instead of `*`:

```
select 
t.id,t.valA,t.valB,t.valC
from (
    select id
           ,valA
           ,valB
           ,valC
           ,count(*) over (partition by id, valb, valc) cnt
    from mytest1
) t where cnt > 1;
```